# HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, tomcat

Доброго времени суток! код сервлета:

```
package myServlets;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class GetCookieServlet extends HttpServlet{
    public void doGet(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Cookie[] cookie = request.getCookies();

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<b>");
        for(int i=0;i<cookie.length;i++)
        {
            String name = cookie[i].getName();
            String value = cookie[i].getValue();
            pw.println(name+" = "+value);
        }

        pw.println("</b>");
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

сервер tomcat 7.0.4; 
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не переопределили метод doGet, а перегрузили его. Порядок параметров request и response перепутан. Используйте аннотацию @Override, это поможет избежать подобных ошибок, т.к. и IDE и компилятор подскажут вам о проблеме.